# IIf And conditional Statement in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements, iif

I am trying to use a conditional statement in order to hide the fields that meet certain criteria in my report.

What I really want is : **hide every field where header = "budget" and description contains "*ratio"**

Here is what I came up with : -

```
=IIf((Fields!Header.Value="Budget" And (Fields!Acc__Schedule_Line_Description).ToString().Contains("*ratio")),true,false)
```

But it is hiding EVERY field.

Comment: Is the * part of the string or is it used as a wildcard?

Comment: The * is supposed to be a wildcard.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use wildcards with **Contains**.

Comment: Thanks that is definitely part of the problem.